# I can't load a link from a textBox c#

Tags: c#, string, selenium-webdriver, url, selenium-chromedriver

The point is that I would like to be able to paste the link to the textBox and after clicking the button, I would like this link to be loaded. I don't know how to go about it too much

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            string url = textBox1;
            ChromeDriver driver;
            Thread th;
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: Do you have an event handler for your button? Second, the way to get text out of a textbox is to use the `Text` property: `textBox1.Text`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
string url = textBox1;
```

to

```
string url = textBox1.Text;
```